# How to avoid loop in Flash files in android

Tags: android, flash

After mentioning God, I must tell u a little story about my problem.
I need to make a simple (teaching) mobile game for the my son so I've tried Unity and seen it complicated and without a good library reference (unlike Arduino), tried Flash professional (why old ver? it was enough) and seen complicated too. Finally I backed to my young years and tried SWiSH MAX 4 ( I know it's weak but was enough for my purpose). The results (SWF 10) were good in PC.
When I tried it in the my phone, some issues tried to crush me!!!!
1-there is just one real and strong flash player available (adobe player, which is a web plugin originally).
2-There is no setting to avoid loop in end of Flash files, **in android flash player**.
3-The android flash player doesn't do this simple script "stop();".

these issues avoids to run my Flash game correctly in Android. Could u help me?

Comment: I understand it is not what you hope to hear, still I advise to give **Unity** another opport**unity**. 1. Flash is dead. One way or another you are going to have troubles just because of the fact. 2. Mobile platforms grow, release new requirements and features. Flash didn't keep up **EVEN** when it was actively supported by Adobe. 3. Flash Player eats a lot of battery on mobile devices because it uses **CPU**-rendering. There are **GPU**-oriented frameworks, but working with them is not simple either.

Comment: The best would be using Flash Professional to make an Android app (result is installable APK, not some SWF file that needs a browser or the Flash Player plugin)... What's complicated about Unity or Flash Pro... Is it their coding languages or their export process?

Comment: @VC.One i've used gamemaker studio and found it very user-friendly, and built my game (i can't publish it yet). I'm similar with C-like codes, but each language has identical reference (unity problem ).  In adobe professional, my problem is different: no straight way is accessible in some cases. For exmp. to show a symbol (movie clip)  in a specific frame and remove in another.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to AIR, which is just the Flash runtime with access to more cool stuff.

It can then be built as a normal android application. And since it's the real runtime, it will have no issues with basic actionscript.